# How to print Arabic and English text together using Python's fpdf library

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf, python-3.9, python-3.11

```
pdf.multi_cell(w=150, h=5, txt="تمانتمانتمانتمانتم English Letters")
```

"English Letters" is rendered as a row of rectangles in the output:

[image]

I also tried using arabic_reshaper
Example code snippet:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
pdf.set_xy(9, 132)
pdf.multi_cell(w=150, h=5, txt=bidi_text)
```

...but it didn't work. Are there any other possible ways to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of the FPDF library answered my question in respective discussion forum

checkout the solution and the desired outcome attached in the post: https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2/discussions/583